# How can I add a newsfeed from a subsite to a page?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, newsfeed

I have a site (A) with two subsites (B and C). Subsites B and C both have newsfeeds. I am trying to display the newsfeeds of B and C on a page on site A. This is all SharePoint 2013 and I haven't had any luck after doing an hours worth of Google searches. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One quick way would be if you could use the RSS-feed web part. https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Add-RSS-Feeds-to-your-SharePoint-site-51847e78-5c74-4877-9fb9-940000885a5f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: Thanks user19952. For a sitefeed web part, how would I get the RSS feed associated with it? I couldn't find one for the Microfeed list which is what I'm assuming drives the site feed.